# Do we have an API to get the Managed Packages of the user?

Tags: api, managed-package

Do either of these exist:

1. API to get the Managed Packages of the user?
2. API to set the Managed Packages of the user?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [UserPackageLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userpackagelicense.htm) like a normal object. You can query the object to determine if a user has a given package assigned to them, insert new records to assign a package, and delete them to remove a package. This works both in Apex Code and the various API's (SOAP, REST, etc).

## Retrieving

```
UserPackageLicense[] licenses = [SELECT PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix 
    FROM UserPackageLicense
    WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

## Setting

```
PackageLicense license = [SELECT Id FROM PackageLicense WHERE NamespacePrefix = :aPrefix];
UserPackageLicense userLicense = new UserPackageLicense(UserId=UserInfo.getUserId(), 
     PackageLicenseId=license.Id);
insert userLicense;
```

## Removing

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM UserPackageLicense 
     WHERE PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix = :aPrefix AND UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```